# PHP 8 on IIS 2019: Sometimes Session can not be written

Tags: php, session, iis-10

From time to time I get the classic "Failed to read session data" error on my application running on php 8, IIS 2019. This is usually associated with a) the directory does not exist b) the permissions are not set. I can rule out both cases.

Sessions are stored in c:/Temp/phpsessions. All read/write permissions are set correctly. Most of the times there is no problem. But if users doesn't log in for a while I get the following warning and the app does not work.

```
PHP Warning: session_start():open(C:\temp\phpsessions\sess_221kd8pv25fvefq@tnph9fhoss,O_RDWR)failed:Permission denied(13)...
```

Again, the session_path is set in php.ini, most of the time everything works. I thought maybe the session key does not have a corresponding session file anymore. But that should not generate an error but a new session. What am I missing?

I tried to store Session Variables and start the session with session_start(). I expect an old session to be invalid and not cause a permission denied warning. I expect a new empty session to be created.

Comment: The "Failed to read session data" error can occur for a number of reasons, it may be caused by a misconfiguration of the PHP process. Check the `session_handler` parameter in the PHP process handler. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php

Comment: YurongDai: thanks. I will try to log the process, good idea.

Comment: I turned this comment into an answer, if it helps you, you can mark it, I hope it may help more people with similar problems in the future.

Comment: After some testing PHP seems to work fine. The problem seems to be with user permissions. We had the same problem in our app in another folder where php has to read files from. We investigate the configuration of the machine to see, why in some cases the permissions are not sufficient. Hopefully we can solve it soon and I can post an answer and close this question.

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution to your problem? We look forward to your answer.

Comment: YurongDai - sadly no, we are now in contact with a windows expert. It seems that PHP/IIS are working as intended. But there is an issue with writing permissions that seem to be not predictable. I will post the solution when we found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had problems with permissions of authenticated users. The temp folder should have been accessible to everyone, but it seems the folder was deleted and created again with different permissions. The mysteries of working with computers …

Answer (score 1):

The "Failed to read session data" error can occur for a number of reasons, it may be caused by a misconfiguration of the PHP process. Check the session_handler parameter in the PHP process handler. For more information, please refer this [document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php). Hope this idea helps you.

Comment: YurongDai I will let you know. It's hard to debug, because most of the time it works.